# Spring data MongoDB search array elements with an order

Tags: java, arrays, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have got a collection named `places` in my Mongo database and then I have got the below two documents:

**Document1:**

```
{
    "place" : "PLACE_AD",
    "routeMap" : [ 
        {
            "location" : "A",
        },
        {
            "location" : "B",
        },
        {
            "location" : "C",
        },
        {
            "location" : "D",
        }
     ]
}
```

**Document2:**

```
{
    "place" : "PLACE_DA",
    "routeMap" : [ 
        {
            "location" : "D"
        },
        {
            "location" : "C"
        },
        {
            "location" : "B"
        },
        {
            "location" : "A"
        }
     ]
}
```

**Mongo DB Query:**

```
db.places.find({ 'routeMap.location' : { '$all' : ['A', 'B'] } });
```

**spring-data-mongodb Query:**

```
@Repository
public interface PlacesRepository extends MongoRepository<Place,String> {
   @Query(value = "{ 'routeMap.location' : { $all: ?0 } }")
   public List<Place> findByExactLocations(List<String> locations);
}
```

**Current Output:**

Returns both the documents

**Required output:**

Only the first document with location from A->B->C->D (not the one with D->C->B->A)

**Explanation on what I am looking for:**

Here, the issue is that the above query returns both the documents because `routeMap.location` array elements match both `A` and `B` i.e., the query does not specify any order for
 the array elements.
So, now how can I modify the query such that it returns as per my required output i.e., the query should check the array elements order?

Also, just note that the **array indexes of the `location` are NOT fixed** (i.e., `location` `A` and `B` can exist at any index inside the array).

Comment: why don't you use a regex on `place` field ? somthing like `db.places.find( {place: /AB/g })`

Comment: `place` can not be derived from `location`, above example is just a sample `place`, just updated my question as well for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

What trick I can suggest is that you can project your routeMap field into a single string like ABCD and then match it with the sequence you would like.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        { $unwind : '$routeMap'},
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$place",
                "routeMap": { $push: "$routeMap.location" }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                routeMap: {
                    $reduce: {
                      input: '$routeMap',
                      initialValue: '',
                      in: {
                        $concat: ['$$this','','$$value']
                      }
                    }
                }   
            }       
        },
        { $match : { 'routeMap' : 'ABCD'}}
    ]);
```

Comment: I am getting error: `assert: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator '$reduce'", "code" : 15999 } : aggregate failed`

Comment: what is your mongodb version? This will need mongodb version to 3.4. You can check by doing db.version() in mongo shell

Comment: We are using `3.2.7` and can't upgrade, so is there any other solution?